# Is it possible to host the CLR in a C program?

Tags: c, clr, clr-hosting

Every example I can find is in C++, but I'm trying to keep my project in C. Is it even possible to host the CLR in a C program?

If so, can you point me to an example?

Comment: CLR API is a COM API. Basically, you should be calling COM interfaces in C.

Comment: ... and for doing so, you can find an article here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx

Comment: I'm going to be honest and say that I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I'm a C# guy, not a C guy, so that article makes little sense to me. Is there a specific example of hosting the CLR, creating a .NET object instance, and executing a method on it (which I realize is probably fairly complicated)?

Comment: In particular, you don't need the COM in Plain C article at all, hosting the CLR is much easier. It's nice *overview* article though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the above comments hint, there is a set of [COM APIs for hosting the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx), and you should be able to call these COM APIs from both C and C++.

As an example, below is a quick piece of (untested) C code that shows how to start up the CLR and execute a static method of a class in a managed assembly (which takes in a string as an argument and returns an integer).  The key difference between this code and its C++ counterpart is the definition of `COBJMACROS` and the use of the `<type>_<method>` macros (e.g. `ICLRRuntimeHost_Start`) to call into the CLR-hosting COM interface.  (Note that `COBJMACROS` *must* be defined prior to `#include`'ing `mscoree.h` to make sure these utility macros get defined.)

```
#include <windows.h>

#define COBJMACROS
#include <mscoree.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT status;
    ICLRRuntimeHost *Host;
    BOOL Started;
    DWORD Result;

    Host = NULL;
    Started = FALSE;

    status = CorBindToRuntimeEx(
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 0,
                 &CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
                 &IID_ICLRRuntimeHost,
                 (PVOID *)&Host
                 );
    if (FAILED(status)) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    status = ICLRRuntimeHost_Start(Host);
    if (FAILED(status)) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    Started = TRUE;

    status = ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
                 Host,
                 L"c:\\path\\to\\assembly.dll",
                 L"MyNamespace.MyClass",
                 L"MyMethod",
                 L"some string argument to MyMethod",
                 &Result
                 );
    if (FAILED(status)) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // inspect Result
    // ...

cleanup:
    if (Started) {
        ICLRRuntimeHost_Stop(Host);
    }

    if (Host != NULL) {
        ICLRRuntimeHost_Release(Host);
    }

    return SUCCEEDED(status) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

This sample should work with .NET 2.0+, although it looks like .NET 4.0 (not yet released) has deprecated some of these APIs in favor of a [new set of APIs for hosting the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233120(VS.100).aspx).  (And if you need this to work with .NET 1.x, you need to use [ICorRuntimeHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164320.aspx) instead of ICLRRuntimeHost.)

Comment: Any guess why this won't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537338/iclrruntimehost-executeindefaultappdomain-error-0x80131513 ?