# Calling static function of C# .NET in C (ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, clr

I have this class `KernelHelper` which is written in C# .NET Framework 2.0. What I want to do is call its static functions in a C program.

```
namespace Kernel.Client {

    public class KernelHelper {

        public static int testc(string msg) {
            // Removing the message box does not change anything
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg);
            return 0;
        }

        // ...

    }
}
```

which compiles and does not seem to make any problems so far. But calling `ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()` returns `0x80131513` which is according to [this](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.331.1.57/1/) the fact that I didn't follow the correct signature convention. But this can not be the problem.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#   include <Windows.h>
#   define COBJMACROS
#   define CINTERFACE
#   include <mscoree.h>
#endif 

// ...

HRESULT status;
ICLRRuntimeHost *Host;
BOOL Started;
DWORD Result;

Host = NULL;
Started = FALSE;

status = CorBindToRuntimeEx(
             NULL,
             NULL,
             0,
             &CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
             &IID_ICLRRuntimeHost,
             (PVOID *)&Host
             );

if (FAILED(status)) {
    printf("failed 1\n");
}

status = ICLRRuntimeHost_Start(Host);
if (FAILED(status)) {
    printf("failed 2\n");
}

Started = TRUE;

status = ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
             Host,
             L"C:\\svn\\Server\\Kernel\\interface\\bin\\Kernel.Client.dll",
             L"Kernel.Client.KernelHelper",
             L"testc",
             L"My message",
             &Result
             ); 

if (FAILED(status)) {
    printf("failed 3\n");
}
```

Could anybody help me here?

**Edit:** 
I tried it also without the message box and let the function just return `0` but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: [Table 7-2](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.331.1.57/1/) lists five parameters for `ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain`, but you supplied six.

Comment: I am using the C-Interface. The first parameter of this function is the explicit `this` (Host) pointer.

Comment: Try something other than an Messagebox, like writing to a log.  Message boxes imply Winforms, STA, message pumps and the like.  Or, simply drop a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Well, that's a good suggest. I tried it now without using the message box .. just let it return value 0. But still the variable `Result` contains `0x80131513`. I think the .dll might not be loaded correctly but I have no idea if that's true or what could be the problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I did not expect to find the solution so fast and on my own. If you experiance the same problem try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1119052.aspx). It seems not to work for everyone.

All I needed to do is to change the `Platform Target` from `Any CPU` to `x86` inside my project properties.

**Edit:** If anyone can show me another solution I'd still be glad since I can not tell if this might not be a problem anyway changing this setting.

[image]

Comment: Well I posted the main information and even a screenshot for VS foreigners like me. The answer is here + an additional link.