# Is it possible to write PostgreSQL Functions in C# instead of C

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am quite new to PostgreSQL and work my way through the documentation.  I am now browsing through "Chapter 38. Extending SQL" and found that it is posible to extend PostgreSQL with functions written in C and a couple of other languages.  I am wondering if it is also possible to write such functions in C#.

I tried to find answers on Google but could not find any.

Comment: C# is not one of the supported languages for PostgreSQL functions, and there is no official or unofficial extension that allows it.

Comment: If you are new to postgres and databases in general, I would take a look at [Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx) and [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/). That lets you write queries in c# for the majority of cases, and drop down to sql when needed. I would not attempt any postgres extensions unless I had a very specific requirement that could not be solved in other ways.

Comment: _"I am wondering if it is also possible to write such functions in C#."_ - I'll go-out-on-a-limb and say **it's _(likely)_ possible** - but you'll still need a _bootstrap_ or host program written in C [which then loads the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372264/159145) and binds Postgres' exports/imports to some interface exposed by your hosted CLR environment. If you're willing to struggle through _the pain_ of it all you might just end-up as the owner of a very lucrative Postgres extension (or just get overburdened by freeloaders who refuse to sponsor your project, such is life).

Comment: @Dai Indeed, this sounds like a really useful extension that someone should write. Possibly you might be able to do this automatically using the UnmanagedExports C# package, which allows you to create C export functions in C#